# In this R Shiny reactivity chain, what is it that allows a change in the user input grid to "stick" around?

Tags: r, shiny, render, shiny-reactivity

In the below functioning MWE code, exactly what is it in the reactivity chain that allows user input modifications to the matrix input grid to stick from one click of the "Modify" action button through to the next click?

Run the code. Click on the "Modify" action button, make a change (to default values or insert a new column) to the user input grid that pops up in the modal dialogue box, and you'll notice that the change instantly appears in the table in the sidebar panel. When you dismiss the modal dialogue, the change sticks in the rendered table in the sidebar panel. And when you click on the "Modify" button again, you'll see that those changes are still reflected in the user input grid. Works well. I need to do the same somewhere else but I'm having trouble understanding how this works!

I'm trying to completely understand this so I can repeat this feature in another section of code.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

# Function assigns row headers to input matrix grid
  matrix3Headers <- function(){c('A','B','C','D')}

# Assigns default values to first column of input matrix grid
  matrix3Default <- matrix(c(1,24,0,100),4,1,dimnames=list(matrix3Headers(),NULL))

# Automatically assigns names to column headers
  colnames(matrix3Default) <- paste0("Series ",1:ncol(matrix3Default))

# Matrix input function
  matrix3Input <- function(x, matrix3Default){
    matrixInput(x,
                label =  'Input series terms into below grid:',
                value =  matrix3Default, 
                rows  =  list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE), 
                cols  =  list(extend=TRUE,names=TRUE,editableNames=FALSE,delete=TRUE),
                class =  'numeric'
      ) # close matrix input
  } # close function

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    titlePanel('Inputs'),
    fluidRow(actionButton('modify','Modify'),tableOutput('table2'))
  ) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
          mat3=matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default),
          input=matrix3Default,
          colHeader = colnames(input)
        ) # close reactive values
  
  observeEvent(input$modify,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      rv$mat3,
    )) # close shown modal and modal dialog
  }) # close observe event
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    req(input$matrix3)
    rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)
    
    if(!is.null(input$modify)) {
      df <- input$matrix3
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      
      rv$input <- df
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      df
    }
  }, colnames=TRUE) # close output$table2
  

  } # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `req(input$matrix3)` makes the rendering of `table2` (and the execution of the following code) wait until `input$matrix3` is created.

When clicking the *modify* `actionButton`, the `showModal` is triggered thanks to the `observeEvent` observing the `input$modify` input from the button.

In the modal view must be displayed the `rv$mat3`, thus calling the execution of the rv `reactiveValues` and so the execution of the `matrix3Input()` function. This triggers the creation of `input$matrix3`.

Once created, the code under the `req(input$matrix3)` can be executed and thus the `df` table is rendered (while the modal box is still open). Any live modifications to the matrix in the modal box are reflected to the rendered `table2` (below the modal box) thanks to the reactivity, and stored in the `rv$mat3` `reactiveValues()` (with the `rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)` line).

Clicking the *dismiss* button doesn't trigger anything regarding the stored matrix or the rendered table, and just closes the modal box.

When you click the *modify* `actionButton` again, you just call the display of the stored `rv$mat3` again, and so on.